# Pharo pipelining promises

Tags: promise, smalltalk, pharo

**Consider the following Promise class:**
It implements the promises callback mechanism present in many languages. Also goes by the name futures.

```
Object subclass: #Promise
    instanceVariableNames: 'promiseValue promiseError promiseLock'
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'META-Project-[pgakuo]'
```

**It has a few methods but the two methods below are concerened with future pipeling:**

This methods takes a blockclosure and stores its value in `promiseValue` variable all in the background.

```
value: aBlock 
    promiseLock := Semaphore new.
    [[[promiseValue := aBlock value] 
    on: Error do: [:err | promiseError := err]]
    ensure: [promiseLock signal]] forkAt: Processor userBackgroundPriority.
```

This method waits for the complete execution of a block and then gives the value of the previous block to the next block which is its argument.

```
then: aBlock
    promiseLock isSignaled ifFalse: [
        promiseLock wait.           
        promiseValue ifNotNil: [ aBlock value: promiseValue ] ] fork.
```

**To class BlockClosure I add the below method:**

```
promiseValue
    ^ Promise new value: self
```

As such I can achieve a "promise like" behavior as shown below.
The below code on playground does not freeze the UI:

```
[ 12 seconds wait. 12 ]promiseValue then: [ :a|  Transcript crShow: a/2 ]
```

That is, it prints 6 after 12 seconds of not freezing the UI.
However, I need to pipeline these promises as shown below.

```
([ 12 seconds wait. 12 ] promiseValue then: [ :a| Transcript crShow: a / 2 ] )then: [ :b| Transcript crShow: b / 2 ]
```

And therefore I try to store the value of the blocks passed to the Promise method `then:` by adding `self value: aBlock .` This is to store the value of the current block passed to `then:` as the `promiseValue` so that the next `then:` in the pipeline can read this value.

The above should print 6 then 3 but it only prints 6. This means it does not store 6 as its `promiseValue` and the pipelined `then:` neither reads this 6 or the previously stored `promiseValue` which is 12. Inspecting the promise object shows that its `promiseValue` is still 12.

How can I achieve this kind of pipelining?

Comment: In the `then:` method the forked process is waiting on the `promiseLock` semaphore, which is never signaled.

Comment: There is a block passed to ' value:' through the use of "[ 12 seconds wait. 12 ]promiseValue". Inside 'value: the semaphore is signaled 'ensure: promiseLock signal'. In the 'then:', I pass 'aBlock'  passed to 'then:' again to value: as  'self value: aBlock'. I expect the promiseLock semaphore to be signaled there so that the next 'then:' in the pipeline can access the newly updated promiseValue but this never happens. It appears I lose context and I have no solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you only ever create a single instance of `Promise` when actually every `#then:` should construct a new promise. By reusing the promise you are prone to race conditions.

Secondly, you are forking the block passed to `#ifFalse:` in `#Promise>>then:`. I assume that you've made a typo there because that code would raise an exception as `#fork` does not answer a boolean.